# How to GRANT privileges on a table with a condition in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-grant

I need to GRANT a role PUB the read privileges on information about orders completed in the first three months of 2020.

Here is the table ORDERS:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS(    /* Drinkers visit pubs and consumes drinks */
DRINKER     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drinker name */
PUB         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Pub name */
ODATE       DATE        NOT NULL,   /* Order date   */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
DRINK_NO    DECIMAL(2)  NOT NULL,   /* A sequence number of a drink */
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINKER, PUB, ODATE, DRINK, DRINK_NO),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(PUB, DRINK) REFERENCES SERVES(PUB, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINKER) REFERENCES DRINKERS(DRINKER)   );
```

Here is my GRANT statement:

```
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE.ORDERS TO PUB;
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make the privilege exist for ONLY the first three months of 2020.

Comment: A GRANT is all or nothing. Create a view filtering those months.

Comment: How do you make a view that filters though?

Comment: `create view bla as select * from orders where odate between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-03-31'` and then grant access to the view